# Message When Using Entity Framework in an MVC Application

Tags: entity-framework

I add ADO.net entity model to an ASP.NET MVC application and the database tables appear correctly after writing the connection string.

But when I run I see this message.

My table name is `ETAConfiguration`:

[image: Message screenshot]

My database is in another version not SQL Server Express so I click no. Then I get an error in a normal LINQ statement:

```
var context = new MyOwnTaxDatabaseEntities();
List<ETAConfiguration> configs = context.ETAConfigurations.ToList();
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
List<ETAConfiguration> configs = context.ETAConfigurations.ToList();
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Check that the connection string appearing in your web.config file matches the connection string you have in your designer. Sometimes these get out of sync when you start changing one or the other, Especially if you use a wizard to create a new project then want to change it over to use an existing database/server. Also, are you running with a local IIS instance or IIS Express?

Comment: Thank you. I am using local IIS.

Comment: I changed to IIS Express and the same connection string which wasn't working worked now. Thank you, but why SQL accepts the EF calling from IIS Express but not Local ?

Comment: Hmm, it might possibly be an authorization related issue with the configured IIS local app pool, though I'd expect to get something of an authorization inner exception rather than a "not found". It will likely be an issue with either the way the connection string is declared or a combination of SQL Server security vs. the IIS App pool account.  A quick test would be to create an IIS App Pool against your user account and point the website in IIS to use that app pool and try it. If that works then look at the credentials on the original app pool against what has access in SQL Server.

Comment: Is there a certain topic to read that would help me apply this because I need it to be hosted in local iis ?